# I am running mujava. My mutants are not getting killed at all. They are getting generated properly but not getting killed. When i run mujava,

Tags: java, testing, frameworks

I am running mujava i.e. mutation testing framefork for java. I tried to run it using different versions of jdk but my mutants are not getting killed at all. They are getting generated properly but not getting killed. When i run mujava, i get following warning too in my terminal:

> "Note: C:\mujava\result\vendingMachine\traditional_mutants\int_getCredit()\SDL_20\vendingMachine.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.".

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs if you are using collections without specifying the type of objects that you are going to store in that collections.
i.e something like this

```
List l= new ArrayList();
```

instead you can use as below,

```
List<String> l= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Ok sir, Thank you very much for your support. I understood why the above error occurs, more over i also found out a bug in mujava system, and the bug is as follow;

Comment: Once you generate the mutants, you need to remove the '.class' file of original program from the classpath before you run the test on mutants. If this is not done manually than your mutants will never get killed as the test will be ran on original program itself.